# Font Family Quicksand from google font broken on Mozilla Firefox

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face, mozilla

I'm having trouble displaying fonts in the mozilla browser. It looks different from other browsers and appears broken when using capital letters. What's the solution? thanks for your reply. I attached a small sample of the display, actually everything that is uppercase looks broken. Below is my code, I only use instructions from google.

[display on opera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8vw6.png)

[display on Mozilla](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81f8p.png)

[html code import font family](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NEvG.png)

[css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XPVS.png)

Comment: Hi, without any code we can't help. Please provide code displayed in pictures

Comment: I've added the screenshot code, thank you.

Comment: oh, html and css as a code not a picture of code - we need it to answer, please. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask